Made-up terms – a cryptic crossword

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Rocker Scott Weiland ultimately jumped bail (3)
4. (*) Take back kissing extremely unclean free wench, missing female on farm? (8)
11. Leader in colliders located near major Swiss city (not the capital) (4, abbr.)
13. Animal performing for crowds in Florida or California (4)
14. (*) Chinese sailing vessel with metal armour showing digital pictures of manhood (4,4)
15. Knight stands by destroyed tower with ruler, meeting new people (10)
18. Material for new sci-fi robot eschews carbon (5)
19. It spews water into the Marina Bay to drive out old wizard (6)
21. Novice composer Johnny's grown (5)
24. Freaking rusty dwellings! (5)
26. Administration's starting to disentangle the BBC? (6)
28. "Tweet crap every now and then!" spearheaded by Χ (5)
33. Are you there to hug sister struggling, hanging in there? (10)
34. (*) Lady parts company, essentially, in Wellington? (5,3)
36. She answers to Picard, true king of Picardy (4)
37. Ultimately, fifth Beatle album (4)
38. (*) Best friend and worst enemy is, for real, vomiting (8)
39. Money – it makes this world go round! (3)
Down
1. (*) Guy who enjoys Friendship Is Magic hides extremes in egotism – he's a close friend who will absolutely stab you in the back (7)
2. (*) "Perfect ten" car broken (6)
3. Freestyle rapper Eyedea knew financial backers followed around (5)
5. Northern Europeans scrap pulse transmitters (7)
6. Like Sly and the Family Stone's music, i.e. pretty bad (5)
7. Uncovering indictment, arraigning head of state – beginning of uprising? (6,2)
8. Festival music for the Oilers, for short? (3, abbr.)
9. Penn's comedic partner dresses in cotton fabric (5)
10. Partially human, chiefly anthropomorphic visitor from space (4)
12. Topless hunter's aide some observers so eyed? (5)
16. Component of financial Europe? (3)
17. Show wrong and right side POV to be shaky (8)
20. They're prepared in Italy for a violin piece (7)
22. Pass over is a religious festival (3)
23. In retrospect, the Ghost-Spider, to her friends in real life, reveals show using many made-up terms, such as seven marked with asterisks here? (3,4)
25. "This is more than I can handle", as said by a zoomer from Japan, perhaps unendingly upset (3,2, abbr.)
27. (*) Minnesota team gives up top position in NHL for Vancouver, and then Montreal, ultimately leading to salacious feelings (6)
29. He played Batty in a Scott film and Gold in a Jonze film (5)
30. Gumshoes such as myself and these people can investigate mail fraud, among other things (5, abbr.)
31. Tell principal to leave club (5)
32. Quarrel about wasted hours as the long-awaited weekend approaches (4, abbr.)
35. Johnny and Ehren's castmate in Disney film shunned like David Bowie? (3)

Here's the completed grid:

 

Thanks for an excellent puzzle, Jafe! As suggested by 23 down, all of the starred clues are

Made-up words and phrases from the TV series New Girl.
4A. "Un-French": to take back a kiss (the opposite of "French")
14A. "Junk Mail": euphemism for "dick pic"
34A. "Gumbo pot": Jess's euphemism for her "lady parts"
38A. "Fremesis": Portmanteau of "friend" and "nemesis"
1D. "Bronemy": Portnamteau of "bro" and "enemy"
2D. "Nectar": According to Schmidt, it's a "volleyball term" meaning perfect
27D. "Twirls": Jess refers to lascivious feelings as the "dirty twirls"

Clue explanations, across:

1. BOND - weilanD
4. UncleaN + FREE WENCH - EWE
11. Colliders + bERN &lit.
13. OR + CA
14. JUNK + MAIL
15. N + TOWER* + KING
18. N + CYLON - C
19. MERLION - O
21. triple definition
24. RUSTY*
26. Administration + UNTIE (referring to a certain nickname)
28. CHI + cRaP
33. P(SISTER*)ING
34. GUMBO(comPany)OT
36. T + ROI
37. fiftH beatlE + LP &lit.
38. FR + EMESIS
39. double definition

Down:

1. BRON(EgotisM)Y
2. (TEN CAR)*
3. C + rappeR eyedeA kneW financiaL
5. N + EUROPEANS - PEA (not 100% sure on this one since it seems like PEA really means a lack of pulse)
6. double definition
7. RA(KING + Uprising)P
8. double definition
9. CH(IN)O (referring to John Cho and Kal Penn)
10. Human + ALF
12. bEAGLE
16. financiaL EUrope &lit.
17. (R + SIDE POV)*
20. foR A VIOLIn
22. DIE<
23. GWEN< + IRL
25. EMPIRe<
27. TWINS with Nhl -> (vancouveR montreaL)
29. H(AU)ER
30. double/cryptic definition ("us PIs" and the USPIS)
31. pUTTER
32. (FIGHT - H)<
35. BAMBI - BI (definition referring to the cast of Jackass)


Nice work! rot13(gur crn vf n chyfr (glcr bs irtrgnoyr))

Ah that makes a lot more sense - that meaning is new to me :)
